# ECharts automatic height

Tags: javascript, html, echarts

Is it possible to create ECharts line chart without specifying it's container height - make it responsive to the actual data.

The number of items in Y axis can vary.

By default, when I don't define the height of the container, it will be 0 and the chart is not visible.

---

In this example there are 6 items (months) in Y axis, but what if I wanted to show 12 months in the same container, without making the bars 50% narrower?
[image]

Comment: How would it know the height? Every chart I've ever seen requires that you pass in dimensions. As your data changes, the size would have to change, that would be really ugly.

Comment: The area before and after the actual chart is fixed and the chart area would be responsive to the number of rows, bars or whatever the data type?

Comment: I don't really get it, how could the size change when the dimensions are defined? How is this done in the other charts then?

Comment: There is nothing in a chart that has intrinsic size. A div can grow to its  content because  text has intrinsic size, so do images (png and jpeg, not vector based images. A chart stretches to fill its container. You are saying if there's more data, you want it taller. I guess one could tell the chart how many pixels per data value on the y axis, but I have never seen a charting solution that does that. I've worked with flot, Ext-JS and wijmo charts

Comment: Okay, seems that this really is the case here. Added an image to clarify the issue though.

Comment: By the way, your solution seems really simple, does it bother you that much? I wouldn't think twice about using it.

Comment: Yes, figured that after asking the question. Will continue using it for now. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know how many rows or bars you are going to have, you can use it to calculate the height of the container.

For example, if each row is 31px and fixed height of graph header & footer is 200px you could use:

```
var chartHeight = dataValues.length * 31 + 200;
$('#graph-container').css({'height': chartHeight});
```